# Magmi importer not associating simple products, not associating images or some attributes

Tags: image, magmi, simple-product, configurable-product

I used the attached spreadsheet to upload a configurable product and some simple products that are to be associated with the configurable. I used Magmi to upload the items and and not only did the images not populate in the items but some attributes didn't either. In addition, the configurable was not created or associated with the simple products. What am I doing wrong?

Best,

Ariel

I just realized that the file I linked to this page was not really viewable. Let's try this one. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/172Duq3_iuLoT0PUUsmD9JAQ6bihfwf6VNyDn2yAAdOQ/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

**Ok regarding the configurable not being created and associated with the simples.**
It's because the configurable needs to be the last one in sequence so for example you need to have it running as

M54808-W-B-Parent-36R
M54808-W-B-Parent-38R
M54808-W-B-Parent-40R
M54808-W-B-Parent-42R
M54808-W-B-Parent-44L
M54808-W-B-Parent-44R
M54808-W-B-Parent-46R
M54808-W-B-Parent-48L
M54808-W-B-Parent-48R
M54808-W-B-Parent-50L
M54808-W-B-Parent-52L
M54808-W-B-Parent-54L
M54808-W-B-Parent-56L
M54808-W-B-Parent

**RE: images not importing**
Check the path you have set in the Magmi Image attributes processor, default is media/import so if you haven't changed it then that is where it's trying to pull your images from.

**Some attributes not importing**
Without knowing which attributes aren't importing, it's hard to help with this one.
I know from experience that some attributes, although when you do a dataflow profile export come out as plain english but in fact they are referenced through ID's (so for example brand XYZ should really be imported out as 4) . The way I check this is that I use the firebug extension for firefox, then right click on a attribute and choose inspect this element in firebug and that will tell me the ID for the selection.